# plot for every criterial

Tags: python, for-loop, plot, powerbi

I am trying to plot every serial number in Power Bi using Python. I want to do it with a for loop.

I tried this:

```
x = dataset['mrwSmpVWi']
c = dataset['c']
a = dataset['a']
b = dataset['b']

y = (c / (1 + (a) * np.exp(-b*(x))))

for number in dataset['Seriennummer']
    plt.plot(x,y, linewidth = 4)
    plt.title("TEST")
    plt.xlabel('Wind in m/s')
    plt.ylabel('Leistung in kWh')
    plt.xlim(0,25)
    plt.ylim(0,1900)
    plt.show()
```

Do I need to define number or can I just say plot the graph for every serial number?

This is my Error:

```
Error Message:
Þŷτĥоň şĉŗιρт έŕгοґ.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 33, in <module>
    for number in dataset['Seriennummer']:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Seriennummer'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "define number"? What is the error you are receiving? Also you should have a `:` after your for loop header.

Comment: @rassar I don't know if number is a command or if I need to say number=.....

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi I don't know how many graphs I have so I want to keep it open I want to see every graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error tells you your dataset has no column called "Seriennummer". Make sure such a column actually exists in your database. See [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Also, you seem to plot the same thing in every plot. Not sure if this is what you want or you simplified it for your [mre], but just something to keep in mind. You usually want different things in each plot, so you'd be calculating `x` and `y` *inside* the loop.

```
for index, row in dataset.iterrows():
    number = row['Seriennumber']
    x = row['mrwSmpVWi']
    c = row['c']
    a = row['a']
    b = row['b']
    y = (c / (1 + (a) * np.exp(-b*(x))))

    plt.plot(x, y, linewidth = 4)
    # plt.whatever else...
```

You can open a new figure using [`plt.figure()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html).

You can create a new subplot using [`plt.subplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html)

You can save an existing figure using [`plt.savefig()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html)

You can clear the current figure using [`plt.clf()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clf.html)

`pyplot` has `hold = True` by default, so plotting repeatedly without `plt.show()` will add more lines to the same plot.

```
for number in dataset['Seriennummer']:
   # plt.whatever...
   # REMEMBER, NO PLT.SHOW()

# show the plot AFTER you've plotted everything
plt.show()
```

So, to overwrite the same figure, but save it to png before creating the new one, you'd do this:

```
for number in dataset['Seriennummer']:
   # plt.whatever...
   plt.savefig(f"./plot{number}.png") # Saves as a png
   plt.clf() # Clears figure
```

To create a new figure every time (so you don't need to overwrite the previous one), you'd do this:

```
for number in dataset['Seriennummer']:
   plt.figure()
   # plt.whatever...
   plt.savefig(f"./plot{number}.png") # Saves as a png
```

To create a grid of subplots, you'd do this:

```
nrows = 3
ncols = math.ceil(len(dataset['Seriennummer']) / nrows)
for plotnum, number in enumerate(dataset['Seriennummer']):
   plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, plotnum)
   # plt.whatever...

# after loop is done, save
plt.savefig(f"./plot_all.png") # Saves as a png
```